# How to set a audio file as a ringtone in Android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use this below code but is working only down to android 10.

This is how I save the audio file.

```
 File ringtoneuri = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES);
                Random r = new Random();
                int i1 = r.nextInt(450 - 280) + 280;
                File newSoundFile = new File(ringtoneuri, name+i1+".mp3");

                Uri mUri = Uri.parse(path);
```

The file is saved DIRECTORY_RINGTONES.

```
                ContentResolver mCr = v.getContext().getContentResolver();
                AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
                try {
                    soundFile = mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    soundFile = null;
                }

                try {
                    byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
                    assert soundFile != null;
                    FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
                    int i = fis.read(readData);

                    while (i != -1) {
                        fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                        i = fis.read(readData);
                    }

                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }
```

My file is set as ringtone but is not working( I got something like 12165016516 instead of the sound name, in sound settings, this is happening only in android 11 )

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, newSoundFile.getName());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

                Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Sound was set!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Every think is working i don t have erros.

```
try {
                    if (checkSystemWritePermission()) {
                        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(popUp.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                        Toast.makeText(popUp.this, "Set as Ringtone successfully! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(popUp.this, "Allow modify system settings ==> ON ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("rington",e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(popUp.this, "Unable to set as Ringtone! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

I'm mentioning that requestLegacyExternalStorage is set to "true" in my manifert.xml file.

**What is the problem Please Help!!**

Comment: Please start your code with defining newSoundFile. We have no idea which file that would be. Further you are not telling us what goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry I was in a hurry when I ask the question. I edit my Question now. Sorry Again.

Comment: `File ringtoneuri = Environment.getExte....` Why are you calling that an ur? Unreadble code.

Comment: ` Uri mUri = Uri.parse(path);` You did not define 'path';

Comment: `I got something like 12165016516 instead of the sound name, ` Where do you get/see that. And what would be the name? `new File(ringtoneuri, name+i1+".mp3");` What is 'name'?

Comment: Why arent you using `.DISPLAY_NAME` column? And do not use `.DATA` column for Android 10+ devices but `.RELATIVE_PATH`.

Comment: `Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);` You are not copying a file to that uri. And the file you try to insert() there already exists. No good idea. If the file already exists you should let the mediastore scanner scan the file. You will get an uri then.